# NSFetchedResultsController with NSIncrementalStore

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsincrementalstore

I have a very basic in-memory implementation of a `NSIncrementalStore` subclass. It works as expected, it just fetches for now.

I am trying to bind it to an `UITableView` with a `NSFetchedResultsController`, but I am not getting the updates (yes, I am the delegate); I also tried subscribing to `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` notification, it is not being fired.

Is this how it is suppose to work? Or am I missing something.

Thanks in advance

Nico

Comment: So you say you are not getting updates but you are getting the data that is there at the start...?

Comment: Maybe is a concept problem, should I get the Insert notification when the request completes?
I get the objects at the start yes, but I was expecting the notification, like I do if it is a normal Core Data setup.

Comment: When you insert do you save the context?

Comment: I don't insert, I just do the `NSFetchedResultsController` fetch request. But doing so you are inserting records in the context, that's why I thought it would fire the notification

Comment: When you execute fetch it will fetch what is stored, notifications will be fired when new data is added/updated/removed...

Comment: Understood, thanks for replying :)